# How to use Poisson Table

Tags: poisson-distribution

[The Question is here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4rGLo.png)

A life insurance salesman sells on the average `3` life insurance policies per week. Use
Poisson's law Pr ( = ) =

<sup>−3</sup>3
/
!
to calculate the probability that in a given week he
will sell 2 or more policies but less than `5` policies

I answered this question by substituting the `r=2,r=3,r=4` as `0.6160`
and when I used the `Table of Poisson Probabilities` also I got the same answer.

I have an issue using the `Cumulative Poisson Probability Table`,
because the answer is given as

```
 P(x>=2) - P(x>=5)
 0.80085 - 0.18774
 0.61611
```

But in the question it is given that the `sell 2 or more policies but less than 5 policies.` Then why should we use `P(x>=5)`. When I tried the question first I used `P(x>=4)` and I got a wrong answer.

```
 P(x>=2) - P(x>=4)
 0.80085 - 0.35277
 0.44808
```

Can anybody please explain what I've got wrong! Thankyou in advance!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your answer you have subtracted $\Pr (X = 4)$. Your answer is therefore too small. You could use $\Pr (X \ge 2) - \Pr (X > 4)$.
Alternatively, you want the probability given by $$\Pr (2 \le X < 5) = \Pr (X < 5) - \Pr (X < 2)$$

But $\Pr (X < 5) = 1 - \Pr (X \ge 5)$ and $Pr (X < 2) = 1 - \Pr (X \ge 2)$. Substituting into the RHS in the equation above yields $$\Pr (2 \le X < 5) = 1-\Pr (X \ge 5) - (1 - \Pr (X \ge 2))$$ which is $$\Pr (X \ge 2) - \Pr (X \ge 5).$$
The first probability in this expression is the CDF from 2, 3, ...

while the second is the CDF from 5, 6, ...

which is a more intuitive way of thinking about it.

In other words you are left with the probability of X=2, 3, 4.

Comment: I understand it now! Thankyou so much!!!

Comment: Great! - It is customary, on the website to accept answers that you find useful. Can you do that? Thanks ...